# Mendeley Desktop processing loop on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, mendeley

So I use mendeley for school, and I just forced an upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 because I royally screwed my kernel when I was running 16.04 (total noob messing with stuff) and wanted a fresh start. Since I upgraded mendeley has been stuck in a processing loop and is functionally frozen because it takes so much processing power. Anyone else having this problem?

I already tried updating it, uninstalling and reinstalling the new version, and leaving it alone to try and finish and nothing so far is working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the linux generic version of mendeley desktop? Just run the executable python binary in the bin folder and this should work before a debian version for Ubuntu 18.04 becomes available. That is what I am using.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. I downloaded Mendeley for the generic versions here the instructions: https://www.mendeley.com/guides/download-mendeley-desktop/linux/instructions

> 1. Open the downloaded archive
> 2. Extract the contents to any folder
> 3. Run the application. Within the extracted folder, open a terminal and run the following command:
>
>    ```
>    ./bin/mendeleydesktop
>    ```